# Is there a Rust equivalent of what bigInt is to python?

Tags: python, rust

Is there a Rust equivalent of what bigInt is to python? If not, then what is the rationale behind not going with python's way of integer handling?

Comment: I'm confused… Are you asking for a Python equivalent of Rust's BigInt or for a Rust equivalent of Python's BigInt…?

Comment: "what is the rationale behind not going with python's way of integer handling?" - it's simple: you don't want such things to be implicit in system language.

Comment: Python/Lisp/... approach to integer handling is not the default in mainstream languages, for various reasons, mostly involving performance. Even the high-level languages with VMs like Java and JavaScript provide fixed-width integers as built-ins. Python-style bignums would be quite out of place in Rust for reasons outlined in cyqsimon's answer.

Comment: To expand on the answers you got, infinite-precision arithmetic requires possibly unbounded amounts of heap memory being allocated, as well as runtime dispatch on every operation to handle non-ISA integer widths. This means there's a significant cost to infinite-precision arithmetics. One which is less visible in a language like Python, but would be extremely so in Rust.

Comment: Now technically Rust *could* have an infinite precision numeric type, in std, dependent on alloc, however that would quite go against the project's philosophy of trying to minimise the size of the standard library, and there's a large amount of efforts involved (e.g. a library like GMP will adaptively use different algorithms -- few of them trivial -- depending on the magnitude of the operands).

Comment: The std library already depends on alloc (e.g. collections), so including a Bigint wouldn't be unthinkable. However, it wouldn't buy the _convenience_ you get in Python. Python 2 had separate types for int and bigint (called long) which were both heap-allocated, and overflowing arithmetic on int would produce long as needed. That would be impossible in Rust where numeric data is stored directly in the variable, and the the variables are strongly typed. Python 3 switched to always using bigints, which also wouldn't work for a performance-oriented language like Rust.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Yes there are. Search for "bigint" on crates.io and there are plenty of results. They are not in the standard library but that's nothing unusual for Rust. Rust's standard library is kept small intentionally to <s>minimise binary size</s> ease maintenance (among other reasons).
2. Because Rust is not Python, and there's no reason for it to "Pythonise". Rust is a systems programming language without GC and with a focus on performance. There are many ways you can go about implementing a `BigInt` type, and there is no universal "best" way to do it. The most performant implementation heavily depends on your particular use case, which again is why there are many crates you can choose from, depending on what you need exactly.

Comment: The size of the standard library does not affect the size of the resulted binary. It does affect maintenance, since if we insert something into std, it needs to be there forever.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman thanks for the correction. Rust only includes in the compiled binary the libraries that are actually used. I typed too quickly there while my brain was half off.